# Drop rows from dataframe that contain characters outside of a list of characters

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to remove all rows from a panda dataframe that are not in a list

```
allowed_chars = list(ascii_lowercase)
data = df[df['Value'].apply(lambda x : x in allowed_chars)]
print(data.Value.tolist())
```

The print just prints a list of 'False' values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing is comparing the entire string stored in the Value column to the list of character you allow, this won't work as your list of characters only consist of one character strings that don't match any of your words in the Value column. Here's what you could do instead.

```
allowed_chars = set('abcde...')
data = df[df['Value'].apply(lambda x: set(x).issubset(allowed_chars))]
print(data.Value.tolist())
```

Comment: this deletes the entire row correct? Not just the row in the column?

Comment: @user8714896 yup, you're essentially building what's called a boolean mask using the apply statement on the Value column and then applying that mask to the whole dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Your format seems fine, and the only thing i can think of is that the maybe the value isn't in the right format for the test in. you may need to do str(x) or something like that in you data = line.  If you can give a snippet of ascii_lowercase and data i can look further.

```
df2
#   a  b  c
#0  x  2  3
#1  y  2  4

df2[df2.a.apply(lambda x: x in 'x')] 
#   a  b  c
#0  x  2  3
```